# How to compile a "hello world" /init process?

Tags: linux, init

I'm trying to learn how to build a minimal initramfs for Linux. I set `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="asd"`, created `asd` directory, inside there's an `init` file compiled using `gcc  -fpic  -static main.c -o init`. In the kernel log I'm getting the following error:

```
                       Run /init as init process                                                                                  
                       Failed to execute /init (error -8)
```

Here's the input source code:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    for(;;);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add the output of `ldd init`

Comment: @stark: `not a dynamic executable`

Answer (score 0):

It works with a defconfig kernel and `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` set. In the directory I had to make the node `dev/console`.

```
mkdir dev
sudo mknod --mode=0600 dev/console c 5 1
```

After running `-kernel linux*/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage` in qemu `Hello, world!` is shown after calling init.