# Why does a custom init fail with error code -8 on a custom linux system?

Tags: c, linux

I'm building a custom init for a linux system (for a thin client) (currently emulated over qemu).
I'm compiling my executable with:

```
$ gcc -fpic -static -nostdlib init.c -o init
```

For some reason when this executable is put over /bin/, system refuses to boot and spits out a error code that is extremely unhelpful (-8). Based on some googling this seems to be corresponding to a signal 8 which is SIGFPE, but oddly enough nothing related to impossible mathematics like dividing by zero happens at any place in the code or in the complicated assembly examined.
The source code doesn't matter at all, any source fails to build but here is a example that fails.

```
size_t strlen(const char* s) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; ; ++i) if(s[i] == 0) return i;
}
void puts(char* s) {
    asm("mov %0, %%r11" :: "r"(s));
    asm("mov %0, %%r14" :: "r"(strlen(s)));
    asm("mov $1, %rax\n"
        "mov  %r11, %rsi\n"
        "mov %r14, %rdx\n"
        "mov $1, %rdi\n"
        "syscall");
}
int _start() {
    puts("test");






    asm volatile(
        "mov $60, %rax\n"
        "push %r11\n"
        "mov %r11, %rdi\n"
        "pop %r11\n"
        "syscall"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

[image: bin/init failing with exit status code -8]

```
Run /bin/init as init process
Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /bin/init failed (error -8).

Kernel Offset: disabled
```

Comment: Also this isn't a duplicate question, other questions has poor answers that doesn't solve the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124849/how-to-compile-a-hello-world-init-process , dev/console already exists in my init fs.

Comment: `-8` means `-ENOEXEC`. The executable format isn't what's expected. Have you tried just running it on your own system? How certain are you about e.g. `-fpic`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I did which it did wrote "test" to stdout which displayed on my terminal. Problem is this doesn't seems to be working at all for a init application, I do not use stdlib or anything. About fpic I tried compiling with or without it no difference, I just thought maybe positions could be a issue but it wasn't.

Comment: Also, why are you building with inline assembly and without standard library? Even on rather small Linux systems, `init` could be built like any other normal application.

Comment: I wanted to quickly prototype it (to see if it works at all before wasting more time on this project) before setting up a standard library like glibc or musl even newlib.

Comment: To be honest, without a standard library your system won't really be able to do anything useful. Unless you want to recreate all the system call and all the standard library functions that you might use. In short, you still need C library sooner or later, so why not simply add it as soon as possible? :)

Comment: @Rob I don't have serial port output enabled in my kernel so I'm not able to share the error code by copy pasting from qemu, would Ocr work?

Comment: When I port kernels, one of the very first things I do is enable the serial port, so I can do debug printing. This should be easy in `qemu` because you can tell it to redirect I/O to a terminal window. You should disassemble the functions that have asm blocks. Note that you should _not_ rely on register data being preserved across multiple asm blocks. Rather, create _one_ multiline asm block. And, you should use [more] asm constraints to clue in the compiler about what your block modifies (e.g. `%rdx`) so it will be aware of this and won't assume it can use it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens if you forgot to toggle 64 bit kernel in configuration before compiling the kernel it may also caused by using a wrong compiler such as a compiler that isn't for Linux but rather was made to produce elf executable for other unixes. Code uses 64 bit registers while kernel is only 32 bit.

Another cause could be due a badly made initramfs.
I had trouble with cpio files until I read the manual which is extremely helpful:

[Using the initial RAM disk (initrd)](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/initrd.html)

While not related also do not use exit syscall on init process well because Init is supposed to be run until system shuts down and exiting init will result in a kernel panic.